# If I overstay in Thailand for just 1 day and pay the 500 Baht fine, do I still get some "Overstay" stamp on my passport?

Tags: tourist-visas, thailand, overstaying

I am currently in Thailand on an extended tourist visa for (which is usually 90 days).
When my visa duration ends I should exit Thailand to issue a student visa and then come back to Thailand.

My problem is that due to my mistake in calculating the day of extending the visa as separate from its following 29 days, my visa expires 1 day before my flight out which was already booked before extending.

Possible solutions:

- Pay a 1 day 500 baht fine for overstaying 1 day.
- Contact Thai Air Asia to early my ticket just by 1 day or cancel it and re-booking (which would raise the price a bit)

If I choose to pay a 500 Baht fine, I don't know what stamp I get on my passport.
Am I supposed to get an **"OVERSTAY"** stamp for overstaying just one day?

### Update

I went to the Bangkok Cheangwattana immigration bureau (Soon Ratchakan; Building B) and spoke with the two officers that issued the extension;
they told me that as long as I pay the fine, it's not a problem; I won't get an "OVERSTAY" stamp.

An American immigration consultant I spoke with told me I might get a small Thai-only "overstayed - fine paid" stamp but it is nothing like the big "OVERSTAY" stamp.

I called the consulate-general in the country I am going to, to make sure "overstayed - fine paid" stamp will not cause trouble in issuing a student visa (if I'll get it at all, as I hope to succeed in convincing the airport officers to use a regular stamp instead); I was told that indeed, one day overstay is not a problem in issuing the visa.

Comment: You can attempt to contact AirAsia (and get frustrated in the process) but you will be subject to their standard terms and change fees, they are an absolutely 100% no-discretion airline with customer services. The end of the world coming wouldn't get you any concession from AirAsia.

Comment: Flights from Thailand are dirt cheap. Why not just get the cheapest round trip to avoid an overstay?

Comment: @JonathanReez this is the last resort though if 300/500 Baht can save 2500 Baht, I'd prefer that; as long as I don't get an "overstay" stamp.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Athough I overstayed just for 1 day, the immigration officers at Don Mu'eng were very nice and told me that I don't have to pay the 500 Baht fine (probably because it's the only overstay I had in this passport); the officer added that if I would stay 2 days or more there would have been a fine.

There is a small deep Blue signature in Thai underneath the departation signature; although AOTM, with my little ability to read Thai, I don't know what it means (I prefer not to post a picture); I assume that's something similar or identical to what the American immigration consultant talked about.

I didn't see the immigration officer inputting anything to a computer and he clued he only have to stamp because of procedure; I believe nothing was noted in a computer.

Also, afterwards, I could get the student visa in the general consulate, as planned, without problems.

Comment: Have you tried a translation app on the Thai text? There is at least one that will pick text out of an image and translate it, which I used once with some success on a Japanese product (i cannot speak, read, nor, crucially, type in Japanese).  Of course, that still potentially exposes your information to big brother, so you might instead try the old fashioned route of asking someone who reads Thai to help you.

Comment: Since writing the answer I became better in reading Thai, but I prefer to wait to read better in general, or to be near a person who reads way better than me, to read the quite smeared word.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the initials of the immigration officer? I've noticed them as well, even in Thai passports, and they seem pretty common when googling: `Thai departure stamp`.

Answer (score 7):

Big tip from foreign Thai resident... If you have any overstays in your passport (dangerous as you can be blacklisted) when you replace your passport book it all resets and you get a new number. Thai immigration smiled when he seen my new passport book and told me my overstays are all gone. I specifically asked in Thai if they had any electronic record of my previous overstays, because when paying the "fines" they keyed stuff into their computer. He told me new book is new record, they keep no record beyond the visual inspection of the passport.

My passport books get filled pretty quickly, but even if your book is not full and you are in a pinch you can just buy a new book if you were to lose yours.

Comment: I thank you for the helpful answer, I gladly upvoted.