# What is the difference between overstay and overdue in Thailand?

Tags: thailand, overstaying

**Update:** I asked the following question based on me not knowing the English term "overdue" and mistakenly confusing it with some kind of overstay (due of similarity between the words);
 I got an answer explaining to me what is overstaying --- well, I know what is overstaying and I already have overstayed in Thailand in the past one day by mistake and even [asked about it here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139467/if-i-overstay-in-thailand-for-just-1-day-and-pay-the-500-baht-fine-do-i-still-g);
 I tried to edit the answer to explain this but sadly the edit was rejected.

My original question here:

> I didn't find a clear explanation anywhere but it was written [here at
>   the Thailand immigration bureau website](https://extranet.immigration.go.th/fn90online/online/tm47/TM47Action.do):
>
> > - Overdue notification is not accepted via internet. Applicant must
> >       contact the nearest Immigration Office in person.
>
> It was further written in the same webpage:
>
> > The applicant (or authorize someone to file for you,only in case of
> >     not overdue), must come to the nearest Immigration Office or Branch
> >     Office in your residence area. The applicant will need to bring the
> >     following required documents:
> >
> > - Your Original passport
> > - Your departure card (TM.6)
> > - Previous receipt of notifications (if any)
> > - Completely filled in and signed notification form TM.47
>
> ### My problem
>
> It is not clear to me how an overstay and overdue (staying) in
>   Thailand differ one from the other.
>
> It is especially unclear to me if "overdue" is a code name for what I
>   can define as:
>
> > `A special extension of generally any visa, due to some special unexpected event, such as a legal issue or acute, urgent medical
> >     condition (such as a car crash) or in extremely rare cases some other
> >     reason for the consideration of an immigration official or the king
> >     (whatever that might be)`.
>
> ### My question
>
> What is the difference between overstay and overdue in Thailand?

Answer (score 6):

A permit allows you to enter Thailand, and is valid until a certain date. If you are staying for longer than 90 days, you must notify the immigration bureau every 90 days. This notification is not an extension of your permit's expiry date.

The difference between *overstaying* and *overdue* is that overstaying relates to *you and your presence in Thailand*, while overdue relates to *the notification*:

If you are late submitting the notification (this must be done no later than 7 days before the end of the 90 day period), the notification is overdue.

If you stay beyond your permit's expiry date, you are overstaying.